# error code Line: 1, Column: 16 Unexpected token '('

Tags: apex

I have this error when I try to execute this code Line: 1, Column: 16 Unexpected token '('.
I checked all the parentheses all of the in the code is correct.

```java
public class MyId {      
    
    public static void show(){ 
        String url='https://drive.google.com/...../';
        system.debug(getId(url)); 
        }
    
    public static String getId(String gUrl){
        String Id = gUrl.remove('https://drive.google.com/.....');
        return Id;
    }    
 }
```

Comment: Which is your Line 1 and getId is a part of getter & setter methods for Id?

Comment: This code compiles in my org. I presume, then, that your URL string is somehow improperly escaped, causing the error you see.

Comment: Thanks! I have the entire url but I cant put it here.